# C++: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

the following code produces this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl nameOnly(char const *)"
```

Code:

```
const char* nameOnly(const char* namewpath)
{
    const char* res = namewpath + strlen(namewpath);
    while (res > namewpath) {
        const char* tmp = res - 1;
        if (*tmp == '/' || *tmp == '\\') break;
        --res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

the above code is a plain c file and I'm compiling it with visual-C++.
I don't get this error, when compiling with C-compiler.

**UPDATE**:
I have tried using `extern`:

```
extern "C"{ 
 const char* nameOnly(const char* namewpath)
 {
    ...
    }
    return res;
 }
}
```

and I get this error:

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
```

Comment: where is string from?

Comment: it points to the line where i "extern "C"{" is.

Comment: Specifically see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574420/492336

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a difference between the function declaration and the function definition.

And when you say "this code is plain C", it's only plain C if the declaration is surrounded with `extern C { ... }` when the header file is included from a C++ implementation file, otherwise name mangling comes into play, which is what I believe this error is about.

Comment: of course `char const*` is the same as `const char*`

Comment: @GregoryPakosz Yes, my mistake.  Editing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a header file that marks the function as `extern "c"` when compiling your code as part of a C++ project.

Inside `nameOnly.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

const char* nameOnly(const char* namewpath);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then inside `nameOnly.c`:

```
const char* nameOnly(const char* namewpath)
{
    const char* res = namewpath + strlen(namewpath);
    while (res > namewpath) {
        const char* tmp = res - 1;
        if (*tmp == '/' || *tmp == '\\') break;
        --res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now when some cpp file includes `nameOnly.h`, the function will be marked as `extern "C"` properly.

Comment: The `extern "C"` should be on the function declaration, not the definition, otherwise it has no effect (if this is a `.c` file when it's illegal, and if it's `.cpp` then it will work as expected).

Comment: Yep I was in the middle of phrasing what I meant properly

Answer (score 2):

```
extern "C"
```

will solve your problem of linkage because it tells the C++ compiler that a C compiler will also need to access this function but a `C` compiler does not understand this use of `extern`.

If you want to solve it you can do something like:

In your header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

const char* nameOnly(const char* namewpath);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and in your .c file:

```
const char* nameOnly(const char* namewpath)
{
    const char* res = namewpath + strlen(namewpath);
    while (res > namewpath) {
        const char* tmp = res - 1;
        if (*tmp == '/' || *tmp == '\\') break;
        --res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: *sigh* we made the same answer, but the first version of my version was messed up. +1 for you